# Why are my combinations of String [] arrays not being added as keys into HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, key, combinations

I am trying to make a `HashMap` comprised of various combinations of a certain alphabet. The hashmap: `new HashMap<String [], Integer>()`.

The `String[]` array is the key, but it doesn't seem to save. It may be the way I am checking?
Since all values are 0, I checked using:

```
int count = Collections.frequency(consData.values(), 0);

 for(String s: al){
         nc = s + "|";
            for(String k:al){
                nc= nc + k + "|";
                for(String l : al){
                    nc = nc + l + "|";
                    for(String m : al){
                        nc = nc + m + "|";
                        for(String n : al){
                            nc = nc + n + "|";
                            for(String o : al){
                                nc = nc + o;
                                consData.put(nc, 0);
                            //nc= ""; If I don't add this, OutofMemory Error
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
         }      
     }
```

Comment: If each value is an alphabetic letter, they should be `char` values, not `String`, and they should be combined to form a 6-letter `String`, which is a much better choice for a key, than array. Arrays don't work as keys, because they don't implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`, so every array instance is a new key.

Comment: @Andreas should I change where I put consData.put(nc, 0); ? Regardless of the change to string, I still can't get it to save into the HashMap.

Comment: Please learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You haven't provided definition of `nc`, `consData`, or `al`. How many values are in `al`, and are they all one letter? --- Anyway, what do you believe the keys to be with this new code? Comment out the `put()` call, and replace with a `println()`, and you'll see what you're doing wrong. Or, heaven forbid, try debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying pre-populate a HashMap in advance with all the keys. I am not aware of the target use case. But usually it makes sense to populate keys in a HashMap on demand. It's a good practice and more efficient.

Anyways to solve your immediate problem. The issue you are facing is because here you are adding same key object (or in this case array object) over and over again into the map and updating the array externally at the same time.

So replacing:

```
consData.put(nc, 0);
```

with:

```
consData.put(String.join("", nc), 0);
```

should solve your problem

It also means that you will need to change you map to Map<String, Integer>. Which is anyways more useful for lookups as well.